# tikzDevice not working on emacs

Tags: r, emacs

I ran the following code with R in the linux terminal and it works fine

```
td <- tempdir()
tf <- file.path(td, "examplelast.tex" )
oldwd <- getwd()
setwd(td)
library(tikzDevice)
# Minimal plot
tikz(tf,standAlone = T)
plot(1,main="\\TeX")
dev.off()
# View the output
tools::texi2dvi(tf,pdf=T)
system(paste(getOption("pdfviewer"),file.path("examplelast.pdf")))
setwd(oldwd)
```

but running on emacs gives me the following error:

```
## (/home/DJJ/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.87.2/latex/preview.sty
## Package: preview 2010-02-14 CVS-1.126 (AUCTeX/preview-latex)
## \pr@markerbox=\box35
## (/home/DJJ/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.87.2/latex/prtightpage.def
## \PreviewBorder=\dimen148
## )
## \pr@snippet=\count107
## \pr@box=\box36
## \pr@output=\toks24
## )
## ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
## <to be read again> 

## ...

## !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
## Error in getMetricsFromLatex(TeXMetrics) : 
## TeX was unable to calculate metrics for the following string
## or character:

##         m
```

I suspect there are some conflict with the preview.sty, but I'm not sure.

Here is a part of my .emacs regarding R:

```
;(add-to-list 'load-path "~/R/ess-5.13/lisp")
(require 'ess-site)
```

And my sessioninfo()

```
## R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
## Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

## locale:
##  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
##  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8    
##  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8   
##  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.utf8       LC_NAME=C                
##  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
## [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

## other attached packages:
## [1] tikzDevice_0.7.0 filehash_2.2-2  

## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
## [1] grid_3.1.1  tools_3.1.1
```

**UPDATE**
A solution [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.knitr/142) suggest to update the preview.sty package, from the one that come with Auctex. How can it be done?

Comment: does [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137231/how-to-debug-if-knitr-quits-unexpectedly-when-composing-tikz-figure) help?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks I have narrowed the problem down and revised entirely my question, but it seems I'm alone on this.

Comment: all I can say is that you must be using a different path/version of TeX via emacs than from the console.  I'm not an expert ESS/emacs debugger ...

Comment: Link is broken (last in page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It gave me a hell of a time but I managed to understand what [this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.knitr/142) post meant. You might as well want to check [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.texlive/499) post if you are on fedora.

basically I installed preview.sty from fedora repository

```
yum install tex-preview
```

then I switch the preview.sty of Auctex with the preview.sty from tex-live.

`kpsewhere preview.sty` might help you find the preview.sty from tex-live (once it is installed). In my case it's here:

```
 /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preview/.
```

Then finding the preview.sty from auctex is pretty easy: It's in the log that I pasted in the question. In my case it is:

```
/home/DJJ/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.87.2/latex/preview.sty
```

Comment: The links are both broken!